# Node not-persistent net connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp

I have a node app that connects to a server, so that my code can easily send data to it since I just leave the connection open constantly. But the problem is that the app never exits because the connection is still active, even after it's done being used.

The problem is there isn't one solid code path, so there isn't one place that I could end the connection. Is there a way to tell node to exit as soon as all the other code is finished, even though the connection is still open?

I'm going for something like [fs.watchFile](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watchfile_filename_options_listener)

Answer (score 0):

`process.exit(exitCode)`

http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code

Aside: It really sounds like the code is due for a refactor with clear socket handling in mind. Refactor early, refactor often.

Comment: I can't do that. There isn't one specific place to put it. I would have to add possibly hundreds of lines of code trying to determine if everything has finished or not.

Comment: I have a hard time believing the socket handling can't be abstracted from the data handling.

Comment: I guess it all depends on how much you care about the maintenance programmer. If you care about this person you will refactor.

Comment: I'm the maintenance programmer. I know what I'm doing, and this is the best way to accomplish what I'm after.

Comment: I'm not buying it. Are you using any flow control libraries like async or Step? What you're describing sounds much more like spaghetti code then it ought to be.

Comment: It's not "spaghetti code". It's running from a CLI, so the code path depends on the arguments.

Comment: Code path depends on whatever you design it depend on. It sounds like you're either not callback counting or using a flow control library. No reason you shouldn't be able to track and close a  connection when you're done with it. If it's hard, it's because your approach or inexperience has made it hard. The fact that you're this far in and just now thinking about resource clean up is a problem. What you're describing begs for a refactoring. You're not going to find some magic function in core that fixes poor designs. Have you read The Mythical Man Month or looked over the Gang of Four book?

Comment: I have no need to callback count, node does that for you.
I just barely started this project anyway, I haven't had any resources to clean up until now. It's not poorly designed. I'm not going to argue with you about how I want to write my own damn code. It works, it's clean, and it's simple. That's all I need.

Comment: Not exactly, it looks at if there are any open requests/workers, which an open connection is viewed as. If no workers/requests are active/pending/etc.. and it has no more user-land code to run it exits. If you perform several async requests it's not going to count the callbacks or watch for errors to determine if/when a final callback needs to be called. In most cases that final callback would close the connection. This is what I'm talking about with callback counting. Look at an asynchronous flow control library like async (https://github.com/caolan/async/).

Comment: The API for fs.watchFile makes it so that it doesn't count as "open", which is what I'm after. I want it to stay open while other code is keeping it open, and when it's done, close it

Comment: `inotify`, which Node.js uses on POSIX systems to support watch/watchFile, doesn't open files while it's idle. It's having the OS notify it of file system changes and then informing any interested user-land code. A socket connection is fundamentally different. The connection has to be open, we don't have any way around that at this time (blame TCP). You're going to have to do your own tracking (or have a library do it for you) to determine when you have all the data you you need. At which time you can close the connection.

Comment: But node also uses it's own internal tracker to tell if watchFile is running, so that if persistent is true, it doesn't exit. It already uses a counter for net.socket too, so they just need an API to reduce the count to make it seem like it's not active

Comment: I don't believe it uses a counter for net.socket. Node.js looks if something is active. If the socket times out and closes it's removed from the table; Then yes the program will exit. But if the timeout is turned off or the connection is active it wont exit (barring the other end of the socket terminating the socket or an network error). In the end, it's up to the user to close the socket when it's done. Typically, this is handle by opening a socket, performing the needed requests then closing it. Node.js doesn't know if you're done asking questions, it only know if the socket has been closed.